# How to "middle-click" on new macbooks

Tags: mac, mouse, macbook, touchpad, opera

I have recently switched to Mac, and the only thing I miss from my old notebook is the ability to middle-mousebutton-click by clicking both mousebuttons simultaneously.

This is a crucial feature when browsing the net as it opens links in a background tab. The best solution I have found by now is holding down Command-Shift and clicking, but this is often a bit hard to do (yeah, I surf on the couch (hey, it's a LAPtop after all) and often sit in strange positions)

Any tips on how to do this on the otherwise lovely and adorable trackpad?

Comment: Wrong, it's a notebook, not a laptop ;-) *"Do not leave the bottom of your MacBook Pro in contact with your lap or any surface of your body for extended periods. Prolonged contact with your body could cause discomfort and potentially a burn."* according to the official user's guide at http://manuals.info.apple.com/en/macbook_pro_users_guide.pdf

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Check out [BetterTouchTool](https://folivora.ai/). It adds gestures to your trackpad or Magic Mouse and there's tons of gestures available to set actions to.

To add the functionality you're looking for choose »Trackpad« from the input dropdown and add »Three finger click« as trigger and »CMD+Click« as assigned action. Now clicking with three fingers will open it in a new tab.

[image: Screenshot of Better Touch Tool with the action set up]

For Safari you'll have to activate »⌘+click opens a link in a new tab«, before it works as intended.

[image: Screenshot of new tab preference activated in Safari activated]

ps. You can also set it to trigger with »Three finger tap«, but I can only get it to trigger consistently when I the »Force tab«, which I for one can't do consistently.

Comment: Changed the selected answer on this one due to the awesomeness of this program!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on Leopard.  Any other ideas?

Comment: MagicPrefs apparently works on Leopard and does the same thing (BetterTouchTool just has more options); try that.
http://magicprefs.com/

Comment: BetterTouchTool is not free anymore.

Comment: Awesome! Lowest license after 45 days trial is 4,49 €.
MagicPrefs goes straight to the trash can. It didn't recognize my new Magic Trackpad so I searched for an alternative.

Comment: BetterTouchTool is very feature-rich, but also very energy inefficient.

Answer (score 8):

I don't believe its configurable within the OS, but [MiddleClick](http://clement.beffa.org/labs/projects/middleclick/), gives you a 3-tap  middle click. Works really well in Firefox, which is what it was originally designed for. You'll need to tweak it so it fires up on logon.

Comment: Wow, great. Aaaaalmost what I need. The problem is that this simulates a command-click, what I want is a command-shift-click (to open in a BACKGROUND tab, not just a new tab).. I found the source code here: http://www.r0ssar00.com/2008/12/middle-click-on-mac-code.html ... Could anyone out there pleeease add a few lines and compile it so it command-shift-clicks? That would be awesome =)

Comment: This has now been improved, so it actually performs a middle-click. Works awesome :)

Comment: It is triggered by a three finger *tap*, not a click. This is a shame as it make accidental triggering possible.

Comment: For those who, like me, stumble on this question years later: the [original MiddleClick repository](https://github.com/cl3m/MiddleClick) is now archived. 

You should use the forked version instead, which is still maintained: https://github.com/artginzburg/MiddleClick-Sonoma

Answer (score 3):

If you use Firefox, Command-Click will open in a new tab.

Or you can hold two fingers on the trackpad and click; this gives you a right-click.  You could then select 'open in new tab' from the context menu.  (or get an extension like Tab Mix Plus and make right-click open a new tab)

Answer (score 3):

> what I want is a command-shift-click [...] I found the source code here: http://www.r0ssar00.com/2008/12/middle-click-on-mac-code.html... Could anyone out there pleeease add a few lines and compile it so it command-shift-clicks?

I've fixed/modified the code to, I think, perform a Cmd+shift+click (if not, try other values for `(CGKeyCode)56` - but 56 seems to be shift)

```
// click.m
//
// Compile with: 
// gcc -o click click.m -framework ApplicationServices -framework Foundation
//
// Usage:
// ./click
// Will cmd+shift+click mouse at current location.
//
// Based on http://www.r0ssar00.com/2008/12/middle-click-on-mac-code.html
// For http://superuser.com/questions/13351/how-to-middle-click-on-new-macbooks/13356#13356
// Modified by dbr - http://neverfear.org


#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSUserDefaults *args = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    CGEventRef ourEvent = CGEventCreate(NULL);
    CGPoint ourLoc = CGEventGetLocation(ourEvent);

    CGPostKeyboardEvent((CGCharCode)0, (CGKeyCode)55, true); // Cmd
    CGPostKeyboardEvent((CGCharCode)0, (CGKeyCode)56, true); // Shift
    CGPostMouseEvent(ourLoc, 1, 1, 1);
    CGPostMouseEvent(ourLoc, 1, 1, 0);


    [pool release];
    return 0;
}
```

Combined with the technique mentioned in the [link you mentioned](http://www.r0ssar00.com/2008/12/middle-click-on-mac-code.html) (wrap the command in a Java app, and use [MultiClutch](http://wcrawford.org/2008/02/28/everytime-i-think-about-you-i-touch-my-cell/)), it should do it..

Comment: How do you set up this in MultiClutch? There is no setting for three-button-clicks, just three-button-swipes..

Answer (score 2):

[Jitouch](http://www.jitouch.com/index.php?page=jitouch) allows you to set gestures, one of which is middle-click.

[image: Jitouch preferences setting middle-click]

Answer (score 2):

[Middle](https://middleclick.app) is a single-purpose app for adding the middle click to macOS for Magic Mouse and Apple trackpads. You can pick from a few gestures for each device, or hold the fn key and left click for a middle click. (I'm the developer, and the app is not free)

[image: Middle app preferences]

[Multitouch](https://multitouch.app) is an app for adding trackpad and Magic Mouse gestures to macOS, and middle clicking is one of the available actions that can be tied to a gesture. (I'm the developer, and the app is not free)

Answer (score 0):

Addressing creating a new tab from a link (with Firefox and Safari, havent tried Opera) using your trackpad and mouse button: you can drag links to tabs to replace the content, or you can drop the link at the end of your tab row to create a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

[Hopefully answering Zarg](https://superuser.com/questions/13351/how-to-middle-click-on-new-macbooks/82155#82155), I've found [somewhere else in superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/27627/three-finger-page-up-page-down-in-safari-chrome/27643#27643) about [MultiClutch](http://wcrawford.org/2008/02/28/everytime-i-think-about-you-i-touch-my-cell/) (which oddly wasn't cited in this question just yet). It seems like it started on early 2008, while BTT is from late 2009 and actually [based on MultiClutch](http://blog.boastr.net/?p=174). I believe it can solve your issue, if you haven't found about it yet. I don't have any Leopard installed to actually try it.