# Three finger Page Up / Page Down in Safari/Chrome

Tags: macos, browser, touchpad

Firefox 3.x has a "three finger" gesture using the trackpad to perform Page Up and Page Down, but neither Safari or Google Chrome has it.

Is there a way to enable this gesture on those applications?

Comment: How does the gesture work on Firefox? Is it only available on the newer (buttonless) trackpads?

Comment: @Jonik: I guess. You just use three fingers and a slide them down a bit and it takes you to the end of the screen. Very useful for instance to navigate from S[OFU] sites ( stackoverflow, serverfault, superuser, blog etc )

Answer (score 1):

Check out [MultiClutch](http://wcrawford.org/2008/02/28/everytime-i-think-about-you-i-touch-my-cell/). It allows you to customize what the gestures do (set a gesture to do a keypress - in this case you would want Page Up and Page Down for 3 finger up and down respectively).

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can do it out of the box. Have you tried some of the third party mouse gesture apps?

Google turned this up with a quick search: http://www.flyingmeat.com/flygesture/

Answer (score 0):

Use BetterTouchTool: http://blog.boastr.net/?cat=4
You can set up many actions with up to five fingers (oddly not with two).

Answer (score 0):

My favorite gesture app that does this is [Jitouch](http://www.jitouch.com/).  The default install now has exactly this gesture enabled for Safari.  It allows you to add new trackpad or Magic Mouse gestures and is pretty customizable.