# True middle click on Mac trackpad under Leopard

Tags: macos, mac, mouse, touchpad, xterm

The answers here:

> [How to "middle-click" on new macbooks](https://superuser.com/questions/13351/how-to-middle-click-on-new-macbooks)

seem to give solutions that work for older versions of OSX, and one works for Snow Leopard.
But none of them seem to work for Leopard.

Does anyone have a solution to generate a true middle click without an external mouse, under Leopard?

(The main thing I want middle click for is pasting into xterms, so if there's an alternative way to do that, that would be great to know too.)

Answer (score 2):

[Jitouch](http://www.jitouch.com/index.php?page=jitouch) allows you to set gestures, one of which is middle-click.

[image: Jitouch preferences setting middle-click]

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [BetterTouchTool](http://blog.boastr.net/?page_id=195)?

Comment: It says Snow Leopard only. I tried it on Leopard anyway -- no good.

Comment: @dreeves: I apologize; I didn't notice it was reported the application is only for Snow Leopard.
In the FAQ, the author reported he will not make a Leopard version.