# How to get a mouse middle click event on a Macintosh?

Tags: osx-lion, mouse, macbook-air, screen-sharing

I am using a MacBook Air running OS X 10.7 (Lion) with Screen Sharing application to view the display of a Linux box running Emacs.  I need a mouse middle click.  How can I generate a mouse-middle click event from the Macintosh without an external mouse?

Comment: For the wheel being rolled, have you tried scrolling with the trackpad as shown in the *video* in *System Preferences » Trackpad*?

Comment: Ah, wheel does work with double fingered scroll, so just need mouse middle click now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is similar to one [previously posted](https://superuser.com/questions/13351/how-to-middle-click-on-new-macbooks) where Kevin Y suggested [BetterTouchTool](http://blog.boastr.net/). I found this to work better than [MiddleClick](http://clement.beffa.org/labs/projects/middleclick/).

Unfortunately the effect of setting a trackpad event to "Middleclick" has drastically different effects depending on the OS and program. because "Middleclick" has no function in OSX if you want to use it natively, I suggest a seperate or similar event to a keyboard shortcut such as ⌘C, or ctrl-C for general use in a Linux environment.

That being said, setting a trackpad event to "Middleclick" works as expected in Emacs.

Answer (score 3):

- Wheel (middle) click: not available by default. Try [MiddleClick](http://clement.beffa.org/labs/projects/middleclick/), it seems to work on Lion.
- Wheel scrolling: Two finger scrolling as shown in the video in *System Preferences » Trackpad*.

Comment: The MiddleClick does not seem to be doing correct thing. I'm getting <down-mouse-1> event in Emacs when I click with three fingers touching the pad with '3 Finger Click' chosen.